# Examples of strict monoidal categories and monoidal categories with nontrivial associators

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, monoidal-categories, braided-tensor-categories

What are some "natural" motivating examples of the following:

i)   A strict monoidal category,

ii)  A monoidal with non-trivial associatots?

For i) the only examples I know are categories which have been strictified, are there any examples occuring "in nature" which are strict, or is strictness in some sense an "unnatural" or artificial requirement?

For ii) I should clarify what I mean by "non-trivial" - basically the examples I consider trivial are tensor products 
of vector spaces, bimodules, representations, and so on, where the associator is just the elementary rewritting of brackets.

Comment: Regarding (i), every monoidal category is monoidally equivalent to a strict monoidal category. An example of a "naturally occurring" strict monoidal category is the category $\Delta_+$ of finite ordinals, under ordinal sum. This is the free strict monoidal category on a monoid object. I find (ii) more interesting -- in particular, I believe there are interesting examples of categories equipped with a tensor bifunctor which admit more than one possible associator, and the resulting monoidal structures are not equivalent. I hope somebody can provide such examples.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "non-trivial" if you don't know any examples.  One might go so far as to claim that the associator *always* consists of rewriting of brackets, essentially by definition.  How about a 2-group constructed from a group cohomology class; would you regard its associator as always "trivial"?

Comment: In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2010.06.024) Mark Hovey studies the problem of classifying symmetric monoidal closed structure on the category $Mod_R$ of $R$-modules for a ring $R$. For example, when $R$ is a field, there is a unique such, and when $R = \mathbb F_2[C_2]$ there are exactly 7 up to equivalence. He doesn't cleanly separate out the problem of understanding non-symmetric monoidal structures, but I think his analysis should probably be enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) [A monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)

ii) Representations of [a quasi-Hopf algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Hopf_algebra)